# iText - new lines in ColumnText

Tags: c#, itext

I'm working on program that insert some kind of watermark on existing pdf document. The watermark isn't image but text generated during program's work. I need to rotate the text, send it to center of page, and those things are done, but the text has many lines. So I put new line character "\n" in Phrase but PDF prints only characters before first use of "\n". How could I overlay some text on pdf document (mainly scanned docs) and rotate it?

My source code (simplified):

```
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
String message = "some\n multiline \n expression";
Phrase text = new Phrase(text);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, text, size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is documented: the `ShowTextAligned()` method is for single lines only. If you want multiple lines, you need to use a `ColumnText` object, define a `Rectangle` using the `SetSimpleColumn()` method and draw the content using the `Go()` method.

If you want to rotate such a `Rectangle`, you need to create a `PdfTemplate` first. Render the `ColumnText` to this `PdfTemplate` and add the template to the document.

Adding the template to the document can be done with the `AddTemplate()` method. In this case, you need some algebra to rotate the template. This is the algebra you'll need for the parameters:

```
a = cosine(angle);
b = sine(angle);
c = -sine(angle);
d = cosine(angle);
e = x;
f = y;
```

If you can't get the algebra working, you can wrap the template inside an `Image` object:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(template);
```

Now you have different methods to introduce a rotation, including a simple one that merely requires an angle in degrees.

**P.S.:** wrapping a template inside an image doesn't "rasterize" the text. It creates a Form XObject (as opposed to an Image XObject).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in another way:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
{
   PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
   String message = String.Format("mutli\nline\text");
}
PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
gState.FillOpacity = 0.3f;
canvas.SetGState(gState);
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(message))
{
   string line;
   float y = size.Height / 2 + 200;
   while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      Phrase p = new Phrase(line,FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 35));
         ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, p, 300, y, 30);
      y = y - 70;
   }
}
```

}